# Backpropogation with self defined loss function and network

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I want to create a CNN network for object localization (It is given that there is only one object). For this I am using some general layers and in the end I want to get the nearest and farthest corner to origin. I am also using self defined loss function which is (100 - intersaction over union in %). Loss is not converging. What may be the problem?  Wheather backpropogation will work with this network or some other problem? Below is the code:
For illustraion purpose see [image].

Network:

```
class convnet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(convnet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=5)
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3,stride=3)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 8, kernel_size=5)
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3,stride=3)   
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=5)
    self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3,stride=3) 
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5040, 1000)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 4)

def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = self.pool3(x)      
    x = x.view(-1, 5040)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) 
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    a = self.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
    c = torch.zeros(a.shape[0], 2)
    for idx, x in enumerate(a):
      d1 = x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2
      d2 = x[2] ** 2 + x[3] ** 2
      d3 = x[0] ** 2 + x[3] ** 2
      d4 = x[2] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2
      dmin = min(d1, d2, d3, d4)
      if d1 == dmin:
        c[idx] = torch.tensor([x[0], x[1]])
      elif d2 == dmin:
        c[idx] = torch.tensor([x[2], x[3]])
      elif d3 == dmin:
        c[idx] = torch.tensor([x[0], x[3]])
      elif d4 == dmin:
        c[idx] = torch.tensor([x[2], x[1]])
    m = torch.tensor([[640, 480, 640, 480]]).type(torch.DoubleTensor).cuda()
    return c*m
def sigmoid(self, z):
    return 1/(1+torch.exp(-z))
```

Loss function:

```
def iou(box_a, box_b):
  A = box_a.size(0)
  B = box_b.size(0)
  max_xy = torch.min(box_a[:, 2:].unsqueeze(1).expand(A, B, 2),
                       box_b[:, 2:].unsqueeze(0).expand(A, B, 2))
  min_xy = torch.max(box_a[:, :2].unsqueeze(1).expand(A, B, 2),
                       box_b[:, :2].unsqueeze(0).expand(A, B, 2))
  inter = torch.clamp((max_xy - min_xy), min=0)
  inter =inter[:, :, 0] * inter[:, :, 1]
  area_a = ((box_a[:, 2]-box_a[:, 0]) *
              (box_a[:, 3]-box_a[:, 1])).unsqueeze(1).expand_as(inter)
  area_b = ((box_b[:, 2]-box_b[:, 0]) *
              (box_b[:, 3]-box_b[:, 1])).unsqueeze(0).expand_as(inter)
  union = area_a + area_b - inter
  return ((inter / union)*100/float(A*A)).sum()

def criterion(output, labels):
  return (100-iou(output, labels))
```

You can check full code here: [link](https://github.com/pawanaichra/ai61002s19/blob/master/localization.ipynb)

Comment: Please make code runnable, and explain what is going wron e.g. include the `import` lines in the code, and the error message or failure in your post. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited the question, please check. Thanks for pointing out.